# CSS "sharing" style between classes

Tags: css, input, styles

I'd like to know if this is possible. I want to define a property in a CSS file, for example a backgroud-color for the body, and then specify an input button that has the same color, but inheriting from the body... Something like this...

```
body {
    background-color: #0000AA;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

input[type="button"] {
    background-color: body.background-color;
}
```

So when I change the background color for the body, also the input button is changing as well.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Sass is great for things like this, I'd highly recommend learning it, or LESS.

Answer (score 1):

Not precisely but [**CSS Custom Properties**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) (also called CSS Variables) can achieve something similar.

Support is excellent in **modern** browsers (including Edge) but No IE.

```css
body {
  --main-bg-color: brown;
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

input[type="button"] {
  background-color:var(--main-bg-color);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
body, input[type="button"] {
    background-color: #0000AA;
}

body {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

You also might want to have a look at [SCSS variables](http://htmlcolorcodes.com/tutorials/scss-color-variables/)

Comment: I always do this... but in my application, in this moment, I have to change all this color, and I wanted to see if there is a possibility to define a color once, and then the other use the same that is defined in another css style ( like having a CSS Object Oriented).

Comment: @DanieleComandini Ok, see updated answer for a better solution.